# Windows phone 8 - maintain free and paid app versions

Tags: windows-phone-8, mobile

I am developing an windows phone 8 application and want to maintain two versions of my app - free and paid. So that my app appear in both free and paid app sections.

Since these two applications will have different Product IDs, is it possible to buy paid app from inside the free app.

I know that if we use Trial API of WindowsPhone, we can purchase paid version from app itself and can unlock the features using IsTrial of LicenseInformation. But in this case your app doesn't appear in free section.

I want  to allow user to buy paid app from free version say by clicking BUYNOW button in app  and get the free version replaced by paid one automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact scenario that Microsoft wants to avoid. They don't want to see duplicate apps in the market because it destroys the consistent user experience. Instead, you need to either use the Trial Library or release it for free and put an in app purchase to remove ads or add functionality.

Comment: Thanks AMR. Even I was thinking about in app purchase but wasn't sure if that the right way.. Now I can go ahead

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to maintain 2 apps one that limits functionality using IsTrial and the other with an in app purchase.

Some people have suggested this isn't allowed, but I've yet to find anything in the requirements documentation that says you can't do this. There's also quite a lot of examples of apps already in the store doing this.

Comment: Why not just do it the correct way and follow AMR's suggestion? Since when do we recommend skirting the rules in the interest of bad design?

Comment: It's not that it's not allowed, it's that it is not the design pattern that Microsoft wants or suggests. It is not only a poor design, it's more difficult to scale, it clogs the market up with duplicate apps making exposure harder and harder for devs AND it makes the experience less consistent and ultimately worse for the end user. It is piss poor methods like this that separate our market from Android and Iphone.

Comment: The difference is the number of downloads you will get. I love Microsoft's vision of paid apps with trial versions. But sadly the users indicate they dont by the number of downloads you get. Being 50th in the free category with an app with reduced functionality will get you more downloads than being 15th in the paid category, even if your app has a trial version.

Comment: @TimGriffiths That's why the in-app purchase to upgrade your application is such a powerful method. You can list as free (and get all the exposure that comes with that) without maintaining duplicate applications. Even as a developer, what you've said is true for me as well. I rarely look at paid apps, but give me a free app with ads and the ability to remove them and you're pretty likely to get my money.

Comment: @TimGriffiths The method that steveg89 suggested has been PROVEN to have the highest conversion rate. If you don't believe me, go talk to Atley Hunter, one of the top selling developers on the market.